# How do I use python 2.7.3 to work on statistics such as max,min,std,pdf,cdf?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bunch of big files (say 20,000 rows and 4 columns), using which I want to calculate mean, max, min, standard deviation(std), probability distribution functions(pdf), histogram and so on. I have a text file using which I would like to get mean, max, min, std, pdf, and histogram plot for values in the fourth column of the text file!

The first column of text file is Name of Model, second column is Year, third column is Day, and fourth column is Value. Each column is separated by comma.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `scipy`/`numpy`.

Comment: You can use the `csv` library to read those files. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: thank you for your response. i went through numpy and scipy documentation as recommended. since i am a beginner in python, would you please assist me on this:for example, I have a file (stats1.txt) in a folder ('c:\\programming'); this txt file has one column with 1000 values; now I would like to get descriptive statistics of these values (mean, median, max, min, std, ). How do I begin writing a code using numpy or scipy? to execute the result in either the same file or a new text file.?? I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific) has a list of statistical packages for python with short descriptions of each of them, you should be able to find one that does everything you need.  I would recommend checking out numpy or scipy, and using matplotlib for any graphing you need.

Comment: thank you for your response. i went through the page you recommended. since i am a beginner in python, would you please assist me on this:for example, I have a file (stats1.txt) in a folder ('c:\\programming'); this txt file has one column with 1000 values; now I would like to get descriptive statistics of these values (mean, median, max, min, std, ). How do I begin writing a code using numpy or scipy? to execute the result in either the same file or a new text file.?? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: This isn't really the place for an extended question like that, normally I'd suggest moving it to a chat room, but since you only have 16 reputation, you wouldn't be able to talk in chat...  But in general, you install the package you want, then create a python file that imports numpy, then parse the file, convert the values to numbers and populate a numpy array with the values, then you can call min, max, std, mean on the array.

Comment: I addressed this in the question you asked specific to it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863745/basic-code-using-numpy-or-scipy If you need help adapting that to four columns, let me know.

Comment: Thank you much. Would you check your e-mail I sent you.